# When will boost 1.36 be available for Mac Port?

Tags: macos, boost

How can i find out this information?

---

Ie,

I can install boost 1.35 with a command like

```
sudo port install boost
```

only to get boost 1.36 via port i would do something like this?

```
sudo port install boost-1.36
```

Hope that clears up my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/16378) is the relevant ticket.

There's a new Portfile in the ticket, and that works fine for me.

I believe the ticket is still open because of issues relating to Python and MPI.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost website distributes source code, which may be compiled on any supported platform (including Macs). It is, therefore, available now.

---

That depends on what package manager you're using. OS X doesn't come with one, so any packaging will be by third parties. If you install software using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), please [file a bug](http://trac.macports.org/newticket) requesting an updated version of the Boost package.

Answer (score 0):

Boost 1.36 is already available for OS X: http://www.boost.org/users/download/version_1_36_0

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but OS X is a supported platform for that release and the sources download is the same for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see you're looking for a MacPorts update, in addition to filing a bug as John suggested, you may find it useful to contact the boost macport package maintainer and ask when it might be available. Contact info is available here: http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=boost